# GENEXUS 16 crear archivos xml con propiedades de procesador de texto

Tags: genexus

Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de crear  un XML  con propiedades de Word en Genexus 16  y mostrar en un web panel  previo de este archivo, gracias.

Comment: Hola Alberto, no logro entender la pregunta. Con el [XMLWriter](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?6938,) puedes escribir el XML, pero no entiendo qué son esas "propiedades de Word" que quieres escribir. Si puedes agrega algún pedazo de código de lo que has intentado para que nos ayude a entender tu caso.

Answer (score 0):

Alberto, en Genexus puedes generar documentos word con el generador java usando Open Office. No se si a eso te refieres.